# How to compute an integral?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I am reading [the lecture notes](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/geom/Whitt.pdf). I am trying to understand the prove of Lemma 0.0.1.1 on page 4. From line 3 to line 4 in the proof of Lemma 0.0.1.1.,  how to prove that 
$$
\int_{F^{n-1}} \hat{1}_{\mathfrak{p}^{-k}} \ (x) \pi \left( \begin{matrix} 1_{n-1} & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) v dx = vol(\mathfrak{p}^{-k})  \int_{F^{n-1}} 1_{\mathfrak{p}^{m+k}} \ (x) \pi\left( \begin{matrix} 1_{n-1} & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) v dx?
$$
Where do we use the condition $\mathfrak{p}^m$ is the conductor of $\psi$ in the proof of Lemma 0.0.1.1? Thank you very much.

Comment: This question, and the deleted answer below, reminds me of a paper I read. The first sentence was "Let p and q be primes." After that, I understood nothing. 

Oh well, to my family I am a mathematician, to my friends I am a mathematician, but to a mathematician I am not a mathematician.

Comment: @martycohen - don't we all know the feeling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really only a statement about $\def\P#1{{{\mathfrak p}^{#1}}}\hat 1_\P k$, where
$$ \hat I_{\P {-k} }(x) = \int_{F^{n-1}}I_{ \P {-k} } (y) \psi ( y^tx) \, dy = \int_{(\P {-k})^{n-1}}\psi ( y^tx) \, dy ,$$ and follows from a general fact  about integration over (compact) topological groups (with Haar measure):

Fact: Suppose $\psi: G \mapsto \mathbb C^*$ is a character. Consider 
$$ \int_G \psi (g)  dg.$$ 
If $\psi$ is not identically one, then the integral is zero.  Otherwise, the integral is the volume of group.

Proof - if there exists $h\in G$ such that $\psi(h) \not = 1$, then $$\int_G \psi ( g )\, dg = \int_G \psi ( h g)\, dg = \psi (h) \int_G \psi( g) \, dg. $$ So the integral must vanish. On the other hand, if $\psi \equiv 1$, the integral is the volume.

The conductor $\P m$  is the largest subgroup of $F$ on which $\psi$ is trivial - correct? Therefore the statement follows from the above fact: $\hat I_{ \P {-k}}(x)$ is non-zero if and only if $x \in (\P {k+m})^{n-1}$, and then equal to the volume of $(\P {-k})^{n-1}$, i.e., $\hat I_{ \P {-k}} $is the corresponding indicator function $ I_{ \P {k+m}} $ multiplied by the volume.

Comment: thank you very much. But in the formula it is $vol(\mathfrak{p}^{-k})$ not $vol((\mathfrak{p}^{-k})^{n-1})$.

Comment: I had noticed that too. But I 'assumed' that it was short-hand (or a typo, and copied over from $n=2$). After all, on the one hand, the above has to be correct and on other, the 'indicator' functions $I$ above have as subscript the ideals, rather than the corresponding subgroups of $F^{n-1}$, which I would have preferred. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Also, the 'self-duality of measure' used in the last equality of the lemma (in the original text) implies a choice of measure, on $F^{n-1}$ certainly, even if dependent on ${\mathfrak p}^m$ (as in Tate's thesis on $F$); yet the text writes ${\rm vol}({\mathfrak p}^j)$. Correct? Therefore - short-hand or typo. Agree?

Comment: yes, I agree with you. Thank you very much.